# Cant use custom font

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I have a custom font called "FuturaLT-Heavy.ttf". Its full name is: "Futura LT Heavy" and its PostScript name is: "FuturaLT-Heavy"

I have added 3 other fonts which is of the same font family "Futura LT", hey all work but this one doesnt.

Ive done exactly the same with all of 4 of them.

1. I added the font to the project and checked Copy items if needed
2. I added it to the key in info.plist Fonts provided by application
3. I added it to Copy Bundle Resources
4. I use it by its PostScript name like I do with the others FuturaLT-Heavy

I ran this to check for it

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames() as [String] {
    println(family)
    for name in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family) {
        println(name)
    }
}
```

But didnt find it :S

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you select the .ttf file in Xcode's project explorer, can you confirm that the checkbox for Target Membership in the File Inspector (the pane on the right side of the Xcode window) is checked? I've had this happen to me before where everything *looked* right, but because the file wasn't included in the target bundle, my app couldn't find it.

Comment: It is checked for my target

Comment: Weird. I also just noticed that you typed "FututaLT" (note the second 't') above. Unlikely, but any chance you've got a typo in your code somewhere?

Comment: I tihng I noticed which differ the Heavy from the others is in the right panel where you find the Target Membership, under Source control -> Status it says "Added" for the Heavy but "no changes" for the others

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the SCM status of the file should matter in this case. One last thing – I've had weird issues with certain fonts that didn't work as UIFonts but came through as CTFonts. An example would be:


[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:@{@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute" : UIFontTextStyleBody,
                                                                                           @"NSFontNameAttribute" : @"FuturaLT-Heavy"}]
                                 size:size];

Comment: Haha this is so weird must be a bug. After I check if I could use it in storyboard (which I could) and then changed the font size of my UIFont object in the code it it worked hahaha, I changed the size from 18 to 30 and then to 18 again... Apple please, thanks anyways man :)